# did wamp server supports ffmpeg in my windows local machine

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

Did wamp server supports ffmpeg in my windows local machiine. If so can I straight away run my code in wamp server to encode video (or) did I have to install the ffmpeg or any related thing to run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAMP won't install ffmpeg for you, that's outside its purview. But nothing says you can't install it yourself and then use something like [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/) to interface with it.

Comment: I downloaded the script then what to do with it next

Comment: Compile/install it? Given that thing's dated 2005, it's pretty old. You might want to look for something newer. It's just an example of one way to interface PHP with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download ffmpeg dll files from here: http://sergey89.ru/files/ffmpeg-php-win32-all.zip
2. Extract and put php_ffmpeg.dll to you php ext folder(D:\xampp\php\extensions)
3. Put the rest of dlls to you windows/system32 folder(C:\WINDOWS\system32)
4. Add code “extension=php_ffmpeg.dll”in your php.ini file located here: D:\xampp\apache\bin
5. Restart apache and run phpinfo() – you should see the ffmpeg extension .

Hope this will solve your problem.